# What is the maximal order among elements in $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z})/\langle(5,4)\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, abelian-groups

Here's a problem about a group : $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z})$

Problem :
Find the maximal order of elements of $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z})/\langle(5,4)\rangle$

The answer is...

> $(\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z}))/\langle(5,4)\rangle
> \cong(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(0,10),(5,4)\rangle
> \cong(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(0,1),(50,0)\rangle
> \cong\mathbb{Z}/50\Bbb{Z}$. 
>   So, maximal order is $50$.

I can't understand why $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(0,10),(5,4)\rangle\cong(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(0,1),(50,0)\rangle$.

Could you explain why it is? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exercise is wrong. The exercise seems to imply that
$$\Bbb{Z}\times(\Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z})
\cong(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z})/\langle(0,1)\rangle,$$
which is *false*. Instead this should be
$$\Bbb{Z}\times(\Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z})
\cong(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z})/\langle(0,10)\rangle,$$
which you should prove for yourself, if this is not yet clear. Then accordingly, the first isomorphism should be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Bbb{Z}\times(\Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z}))/\langle(5,4)\rangle
&\cong&(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z})/\langle(0,10),(5,4)\rangle.\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Oh,,, i make a mistake in writing... I edit it as below. But i cant understand the 2nd congurent relation.
$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z_{10}}/\langle(5,4)\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\langle(0,10),(5,4)\rangle$

Comment: @S.J.peter please try to find one, if you fail but share your progress, then we can help better.